# Transfer Windows 10 license to new Windows 11 PC

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a PC that runs Windows 10 Pro. It doesn't meet the requirements of Windows 11 so I cannot do an upgrade. Meanwhile, I assembled a new PC with latest hardware that can run Windows 11. Right now I have two choices:

- Plug the hard drive containing Windows 10 into the new PC and upgrade to Windows 11. I'm not sure if this can be done cleanly, as I heard that Windows may require re-activation of there are major hardware changes.
- Perform a clean install of Windows 11 on the new PC, and somehow transfer my Windows 10 license to the newly installed Windows 11 system. Afterwards, the old Windows 10 system can be wiped.

Is the second option even possible? My guess is that since I can upgrade my Windows 10 to Windows 11, the license should *theoretically* be able to activate Windows 11. If so, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: If you have an OEM license on your original system it cannot be transferred. If you purchased Win10, use the license key that you got at the time of purchase.

Comment: As noted OEM licenses (the majority of licenses) cannot be transferred. Purchase a Windows 11 license for the new machine.

Comment: Microsoft states that, in order to reactivate windows upon hardware change, you need to switch to a microsoft account, as such that the license key can be stored there. I'm not sure if you do this on windows 10, and then install windows 11 and login with your microsoft account that it will recognize the key, but if your old pc is still working, that is something you can try.

Comment: Here you can check step by step how to transfer windows 10 to windows 11 https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/how-to-transfer-files-from-windows-10-to-windows-11.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have a PC that runs Windows 10 Pro. It doesn't meet the requirements of Windows 11 so I cannot do an upgrade. Meanwhile, I assembled a new PC with latest hardware that can run Windows 11.

You absolutely could upgrade to Windows 11 on your current device you would just have an unsupported installation.

You can upgrade to Windows 11 regardless if your machine is compatible or not. All it takes is a registry key to do so. Despite reports saying otherwise, it appears you will still receive cumulative updates, in this unsupported state.

> Plug the hard drive containing Windows 10 into the new PC and upgrade to Windows 11. I'm not sure if this can be done cleanly, as I heard that Windows may require re-activation of there are major hardware changes

This won’t work.  Even if the system boots it will won’t be activated. OEM licenses of Windows 10 cannot be transferred.

> Perform a clean install of Windows 11 on the new PC, and somehow transfer my Windows 10 license to the newly installed Windows 11 system. Afterwards, the old Windows 10 system can be wiped

This also won’t work since you cannot transfer the license to your new machine.

> Is the second option even possible? My guess is that since I can upgrade my Windows 10 to Windows 11, the license should theoretically be able to activate Windows 11. If so, what's the right way to do it?

The correct method to install Windows 11 today is to purchase a Windows 10 license, and install Windows 11.  Windows 11 is a free upgrade to Windows 10 Home and Windows 11 Professional.

Comment: Or... on old windows 10, switch to a microsoft account login, so the license is attached to the online account, then on the new pc install windows 10, skip key, login with same microsoft account, activate windows using microsoft account and then upgrade.

Comment: @LPChip - Author has an OEM license.  Windows 11 could only be activated automatically on the incompatible device

Answer (score -2):

To add a bit of historical perspective, from Dec 2023, now that Microsoft has EOLed 21h2 Windows 11. The only machines which didn't get the 22h2 ... 23h2 feature updates in the normal course of events are the machines with a "forced" Windows 11 install.

The 21h2 install was straightforward from a USB, no regedits were needed. The 21h1 ISO would not update/install from disk, but from a USB, the install runs successfully (on a 2012 Toshiba and 2015 MSI netbook, with secure boot and TPM 1.2). Normal updates were available, just not the feature updates. The two old machines were running activated Windows 10 Home. After the update to Windows 11 21h2, the netbook maintained its activation. The Toshiba install was done with a Windows 7 Pro key from the sticker off the bottom of a blown laptop (probably never used for activation, as an immediate update to Win 8 was done on that machine). The initial install activation failed, but running activation again after the install succeeded. This resulted in an activated 21h2 Win 11 Pro. Both machines were dual boot with Ubuntu, and the installs did not affect the dual boot setups.  Win 11 21h2 EOLed Oct 2023, so time to try a 23h2 installation.

The 23h2 ISO on a USB would no longer successfully run, it
claimed the usual: "This machine cannot run Windows 11".
That USB hole was patched. The workaround I tried was an immediate shift F10 to get a command window, run regedit, make the LabConfig key with dwords BypassRAMCheck, BypassTPMCheck, and BypassSecureBootCheck set to 1, and the install ran normally. Both machines maintained their activation state, even the Win 11 Pro from the old Win 7 Pro sticker. Again, dual boot with Ubuntu was not affected.

Some "old" OEM keys might actually be usable on new machines.  You wont know until you try.